# NodeJS Google Cloud Service Account Bearer Token

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to get the Authorization Bearer Token for a Google Service Account in order to make REST API calls. The service account JSON key that I got looks as follows:

```
{ 
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "sa-12345",
    "private_key_id": "12345abc",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n12345abc\n12345abc\n=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "sa@sa12345-12345.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "12345",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/sa%40sa-12345.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }
```

Is there any way to achieve this in NodeJs? I can not use Google SDK as I receive as input the URL only and using the SDK based only on that information would require a mapping from urls to sdk libraries (compute, storage, etc.)

Comment: Yes, this can be done without Google SDKs but will require encryption libraries to provide SHA256withRSA signing. I do not understand your comment regarding mapping URLs to SDK libraries. Note: the data structure in your question is called **service account JSON key**. Use that term to get better search results for your question.

Comment: Can you explain with more detail what you mean here: "I can not use Google SDK as I receive as input the URL only"?

Answer (score -1):

This [Node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) shows you how to authenticate to Google APIs using OAuth2 credentials. The example is for the Drive API, but it is the same process can be followed for any Google API.

The OAuth 2.0 credentials are created by application type (web server, desktop, etc...). See [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) for more information.

In your case since you want to use a service account. You will have to build a JWT and exchange it for an access token.

Please refer to the following documentation for reference and example:

- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest
- https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/jwts

Comment: The link in this answer does not create credentials from a service account. The link is for creating credentials from a user identity using an OAuth Flow e.g. login in using a browser. Therefore, it does not answer the question.